# Stream to RDD to DataFrame to CSV

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am really getting desperate here.

What I am trying to do is, capturing a stream, aggregated stream data for some seconds, and after save it as a CSV file.

```
val sparkSession : SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local[*]")
  .appName("Streaming")
  .config(conf)
  //.enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```

So, I am capturing the stream

```
val lines = streamingContext.socketTextStream(HOST, PORT)
val linesMessage = lines.map(_.split(DELIMITER)(1))
```

and count the incidents

```
val counts = linesMessage.map(tag => (tag, 1))
        .reduceByKeyAndWindow({ (x, y) => x + y }, { (x, y) => x - y }, Seconds(EVENT_PERIOD_SECONDS*4), Seconds(EVENT_PERIOD_SECONDS))
```

which is so far working.

Now, I would like so save each windowLength in a CSV file, and stucking there:

```
  val schema = new StructType()
    .add(StructField("text", StringType, true))
    .add(StructField("count", IntegerType, true))

  counts.foreachRDD(rdd =>
  {
    //rdd.saveAsTextFile(CHECKPOINT_DIR + "/output_" + sdf.format(System.currentTimeMillis()))

    val df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rdd.map(attributes => Row(attributes._1, attributes._2)), schema)
    df.write.format("csv").save(CHECKPOINT_DIR + "/output_" + sdf.format(System.currentTimeMillis()))
  })
```

Can anybody assist me with that please?

Sorry, for get the error:

When I just run rdd.saveAsTextFile it creates various plain text file that had to be merged.

By creating the createDataFrame is get this error

```
17/11/12 23:06:04 ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1510490490000 ms.1

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:578)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:335)
    at main.scala.Main$$anonfun$main$scala$Main$$functionToCreateContext$1$1.apply(Main.scala:152)
    at main.scala.Main$$anonfun$main$scala$Main$$functionToCreateContext$1$1.apply(Main.scala:146)
```

Line 146 is the sparkSession.createDataFrame line

Comment: What is the problem you encounter?

Comment: Why do you need the Dataframe? That's not going to fix the small file problem

Comment: You were right. It is more the problem of lacking knowledge ;)

Answer (score 1):

I "solved" it by changing my code like this:

```
  linesFilter.window(Seconds(EVENT_PERIOD_SECONDS*WRITE_EVERY_N_SECONDS), Seconds(EVENT_PERIOD_SECONDS*WRITE_EVERY_N_SECONDS)).foreachRDD { (rdd, time) =>
    if (rdd.count() > 0) {
      rdd
        .coalesce(1,true)
        .map(_.replace(DELIMITER_STREAM, DELIMITER_OUTPUT))
        //.map{_.mkString(DELIMITER_OUTPUT) }
        .saveAsTextFile(CHECKPOINT_DIR + "/output/o_" + sdf.format(System.currentTimeMillis()))
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Possible cause and workaround**

The problem could come from the `sparkSession` which may be uncoupled with the `streamingContext`.

Might be worth to try to get the spark session from the `streamingContext` to ensure both share the same configuration:

```
counts.foreachRDD(rdd => {
    val spark = sparkSession.builder.config(streamingContext.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate()
    val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd.map(attributes => Row(attributes._1, attributes._2)), schema)
    ...
})
```

**Partioning**

As mentioned in the comments, if your objective is to reduce the number of files created by Spark, you can just use `repartition` on the `RDD` directly provided to your function:

```
counts.foreachRDD(rdd => {
    rdd.repartition(10)
       .saveAsTextFile(CHECKPOINT_DIR + "/output_" + sdf
       .format(System.currentTimeMillis()))
})
```

`repartition` should be used very carefully though, as you need to have good estimations of the size of the resulting partitions to avoid under or over-sizing them.